# Correct set_error_handler() Function Reference Links

Tags: php, error-handling, hyperlink, preg-replace

Using PHP's `set_error_handler()` function, you can have the *callable* function receive some parameters with one of them being the error string. Here is an example error string I received in testing (I caused the error to be thrown):

```
parse_ini_file(/MyPath/App/Config/Database2.ini) [<a href='function.parse-ini-file'>function.parse-ini-file</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

You will notice it includes a link to the `parse_ini_file()` function which should point to something like:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php

My question is, what is the easiest way to add the **https://www.php.net/manual/en/** part to the path in that string. Is there a function where I can set the base URL for this or do I have to manually do a string replace with something like `preg_replace()`? It seems odd to me that it would be default point to just the file name...there's got to be a standard procedure for fixing that link other than text manipulation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `preg_replace()` solution since I haven't received any answers. In case anybody else is trying to do the same thing, in your error handler function do this:

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
{
   $pattern = "/(.*)(href=')(.*)(')(.*)/i";
   $errstr = preg_replace($pattern, "$1target='_blank' $2http://us1.php.net/manual/en/$3$4$5", $errstr);
   echo($errstr);
}
```